# What ip-addresses must be assigned to router ports if i need to connect router to 3 subnets?

Tags: networking, routes, ethernet, administration

Subnet #1 has 192.168.135.67/28 **host**

Subnet #2 has 192.168.135.90/28 **host**

and

Subnet #3 has 192.168.135.102/28 **host**

Comment: Any available host address within the network is valid for a router interface address. A router is just another host on the network, albeit the one to which traffic destined for a different network is sent.

Comment: My guess was that i need to assign subnets addresses, for example : for 192.168.135.67/28 host - assign 192.168.135.64/28 subnet #1 address to router port. But i'm not sure.

Comment: No, router interfaces are assigned host addresses.

Comment: But by default gateway = subnet address (if we talk about single subnet). Isn't it ? So if my router ports look at 3 subnets, they mustn't be assigned as subnets addresses ?

Comment: No, not at all. For IPv4, you have the network and broadcast addresses reserved, and they cannot be assigned to any hosts, including a router interface. A router interface can be assigned any valid host address. Most people assign either the first or last usable address to the router interface, but that is not a requirement. It helps to be consistent.

Comment: Thanks! You can write it as an answer and i will mark it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Any available host address within the network is valid for a router interface address. A router is just another host on the network, albeit the one to which traffic destined for a different network is sent. A router interface can be assigned any valid host address. Most people assign either the first or last usable address to the router interface, but that is not a requirement. It helps to be consistent.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming. Please do not answer such blatantly off topic questions. It encourages them, and hinders us cleaning them up.